# Impressão de imagem na impressora Datamax com C#

Tags: c#, imagem, impressora

Bom dia!

Tenho um sistema de impressão de etiquetas na impressora Datamax que é feito em C#. Preciso gerar a impressão de uma imagem (logotipo) na etiqueta e estava seguindo os passos descritos neste fórum :

> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/50e46bce-24a3-43eb-97a4-c65da7df39be/datamax-dpl-imprimir-imagem?forum=504

Porém não consegui progredir.
Aparentemente o processo que precisa ser feito é converter a imagem (.bmp) para bytes, e depois para string e então mandar essa string para a impressão via comandos DPL (linguagem da Datamax), só que no momento que eu mando para a impressão, aparece na tela que o documento foi enviado para a impressora mas não imprime nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

O código que estou utilizando é este:

```
////Impressão logotipo

            FileStream fileImagem = new FileStream("img\\LOGO_DNV.bmp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader imagemTexto = new StreamReader(fileImagem, Encoding.ASCII);
            string imagemString = imagemTexto.ReadToEnd().ToString();
            imagemTexto.Close();
            fileImagem.Close();
            String nomeArquivo = "LOGO_DNV.txt";
            StreamWriter arquivo = new StreamWriter(nomeArquivo, false, Encoding.ASCII);
            arquivo.WriteLine(imagemString);

            sb.AppendLine(soh + "D"); //Desabilita comandos imediatos
            sb.AppendLine(stx + "ICBLOGO: " + cr);
            sb.AppendLine(imagemString + cr);

            sb.AppendLine("1Y4300001500020Logo" + cr);


            qtdEtiqueta = "0001";
            sb.AppendLine("Q" + qtdEtiqueta + cr);//quantidade de etiquetas impressas
            sb.AppendLine("E" + cr);//termina a formatação da etiqueta e imprime
```

Desde já, grato pela atenção.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado

Comment: Obrigado, David! Post editado e acrescentado o código que estou usando.